# ng-repeat adding blank <tr>

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm a newb to Angular and I'm trying to create a table by using `ng-repeat` to generate `<tr>`'s

My controller

```
 .controller('ContactCtrl', ['$scope', 'Contact',
    function($scope, Contact) {
      $scope.contacts = Contact.query();
    }
  ])
```

My Factory

```
.factory('Contact', ['$resource', 'ENV',
    function($resource, ENV) {
      return $resource(ENV.apiEndpoint, {}, {
        query: { method:'GET', isArray:true }
        // create: { method:'POST', }
      })
    }
  ]);
```

my Partial

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>first name</th>
        <th>last name</th>
        <th>phone</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>address</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:searchParams | orderBy:orderProp">
        <td>{{contact.first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.last_name}}<td>
        <td>{{contact.phone_number}}<td>
        <td>{{contact.email}}<td>
        <td>{{contact.address}}<td>
      <tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

now for some odd reason this is the html I'm getting back the correct things but there are empty `<td>` elements.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>first name</th>
        <th>last name</th>
        <th>phone</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>address</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- ngRepeat: contact in contacts | filter:searchParams | orderBy:orderProp --><tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:searchParams | orderBy:orderProp" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">testing</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Test</td><td>
        </td><td class="ng-binding"></td><td>
        </td><td class="ng-binding">me@asdfa.ca</td><td>
        </td><td class="ng-binding"></td><td>
      </td></tr><!-- end ngRepeat: contact in contacts | filter:searchParams | orderBy:orderProp --><tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:searchParams | orderBy:orderProp" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">stuff</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Test</td><td>
        </td><td class="ng-binding"></td><td>
        </td><td class="ng-binding">me@asdfa.ca</td><td>
        </td><td class="ng-binding"></td><td>
      </td></tr><!-- end ngRepeat: contact in contacts | filter:searchParams | orderBy:orderProp --><tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:searchParams | orderBy:orderProp" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">bob</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Test</td><td>
        </td><td class="ng-binding">778-714-3492</td><td>
        </td><td class="ng-binding">me@asdfa.ca</td><td>
        </td><td class="ng-binding">1231 comce</td><td>
      </td></tr><!-- end ngRepeat: contact in contacts | filter:searchParams | orderBy:orderProp --><tr>
    </tr></tbody>
  </table>
```

what is going on here why is there multiple empty `<td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
close your `<td>`
```

like

```
 <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:searchParams | orderBy:orderProp">
    <td>{{contact.first_name}}</td>
    <td>{{contact.last_name}}</td>
    <td>{{contact.phone_number}}</td>
    <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
    <td>{{contact.address}}</td>
  </tr>
```